# Minimum pass in order to be able to reach any destination in the city starting from any place

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

City has an outstanding road network that consists of m bidirectional roads
connecting all `n` places of the city. The city decided to assign each road a unique value `c in { 1, ..., m }` to use as a toll fee for that road in order to maintain it. In addition, it created m passes labeled `i` from `{ 1, ..., m }`. A driver that owns pass `i` can use all roads with toll fees at most `i`. Given the description of the city road network, do the following:

I am trying to find algorithm that:

1. Allows me to find the minimum pass in O(m<sup>2</sup>) that you need to buy in order to be able to reach any destination in the city starting from any place.
2. Allows me to find the minimum pass in O(m) that you need to buy in order to be able to reach any destination in the city starting from any place.

I have some thought about the answer for them:

1. It can be solved using dynamic programming.
2. It can be solved using approximation.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Is this an abstract programming problem you're trying to solve or is this regarding an actual situation you're facing?

Comment: it is abstract programming

Comment: Not homework by any chance?

Comment: Is _abstract programming_ the name of an actual algorithm design technique or problem type or is it supposed to be a joke? I never heared of it.

Comment: not homework. I am trying to have some practice to different algo problem sets.

Comment: Ok, so by _abstract programming_ you mean devising an algorithm without actually implementing it in a real programming language?

Comment: I wanna guide on how to solve it.

Comment: This is a spookily similar question to the one seen here three hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222561/hello-city-has-an-outstanding-road-network-dynamic-programming ... Maybe you can liaise with @Mow1993 on this issue?...

Comment: No, *abstract programming* is solving a problem that has no particular real-world application waiting for the solution.  For instance, most homework problems (which this seems to be, although you broke the SO rules by failing to identify it as such) are abstract.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, there’s a connection between this problem and spanning trees.

Can you prove that if you have an MST for the graph, the heaviest edge in that MST is the ID of the pass you should buy?

Comment: This algorithm is very close to Kruskal’s algorithm. We begin from
the set of nodes V and empty set of edges. During each step, we
add edge e which has minimum cost ce among all edges that keep
the constructed set of edges acyclic. Great this can work on O(m) time.